# How to change background color in ttk.Combobox's listview?

Tags: python, listview, combobox, tkinter

How can I change the style of the combobox's listview?

Here is part of the code so far:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("BW.TLabel", foreground="black", background="#20252b",
                insertbackground="white", fieldbackground= 'blue')
optmn = ttk.Combobox(self, style="BW.TLabel")
optmn.place(x=140, y=200, width=150, height=25)
```

How can I access the style of the listview of the combobox?

Sample Image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit @ajcr !

Comment: No worries - good question, I'd like to know the answer too!

Comment: In a tcl documentation (http://wiki.tcl.tk/37973) i found this:

`ttk::combobox  edit`
`ttk::style map TCombobox -background \`

`option add *TCombobox*Listbox.background color`
`option add *TCombobox*Listbox.foreground color`
`option add *TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground color`
`option add *TCombobox*Listbox.selectForeground color`

Comment: This is really annoying, there's no known way to really customise `ttk`
 widgets, and people say that they are customisable, well, in my opinion, they are a waste of time.

Comment: You stlye.configure a label. It should be TCombobox

Comment: Thanks Curly Joe but .option_add() did the job

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it! the way to change the BG of the listview of the combobox is:

```
import ttk
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()

root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Background", 'green')

combo = ttk.Combobox().pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer to your own question helped me solve mine. So, I figured I'd help you and others by contributing a bit further :)

Seeing your code in the question leads me to believe you want to change more than *just* the background color of the Listbox. I've played around with this a bit, and I'm sure there are some other options available, but this allows you to update the Combobox entry field background and text colors, as well as the Listbox field background and text colors.

I've included an example picture of a Combobox/Listbox from an app I've written using the code below (adapted for this response).

Hope this helps you and any future travelers!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# variables created for colors
ebg = '#404040'
fg = '#FFFFFF'

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()

# Note the code line below.
# Be sure to include this or style.map() won't function as expected.
style.theme_use('alt')

# the following alters the Listbox
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox*Background', ebg)
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox*Foreground', fg)
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox*selectBackground', fg)
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox*selectForeground', ebg)

# the following alters the Combobox entry field
style.map('TCombobox', fieldbackground=[('readonly', ebg)])
style.map('TCombobox', selectbackground=[('readonly', ebg)])
style.map('TCombobox', selectforeground=[('readonly', fg)])
style.map('TCombobox', background=[('readonly', ebg)])
style.map('TCombobox', foreground=[('readonly', fg)])
```

[image: Combobox and Listbox color example]