# Change each item's foreground and background color in a combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I want to change the foreground and background colors of each item of the ComboBox in tkinter. I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545559/how-to-change-background-color-in-ttk-comboboxs-listview) to change the color of the background dropdown menu and with the help of the answer there, i am able to change the forground of items with `root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Foreground", 'red')` but all are changing whereas i want to change them separately to a the different foreground and background colors, is it possible?

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Foreground", 'red')
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=[i for i in range(10)]).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the color of individual items in a combobox dropdown menu.

Comment: I think I've to use a frame with a bunch of labels then :(