# How to add different background colors to different selection options in ttk.Combobox?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, ttk, ttkwidgets

I want to add different colors to different selections in Combobox. I found questions about changing the [overall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64755118/how-to-change-ttk-combobox-dropdown-colors-dynamically) background color, but not per entry.

I'm attaching some examples below.

[image]
[image]
[image: This is an example from your answer @toyota-supra]

Comment: background in window or inside ttk.combobox?

Comment: Like in the images. I'd like different entries inside Combobox to be of different color.

Comment: Sorry about my answer. I did this on  Vb 6.. I will  have to translate it to Python. But uncertainty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ttk `Combobox` does not supports that feature. So it's recommended to implement a custom widget with the `Entry` and `Menu` as in the [ctk_combobox.py](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_combobox.py).

But if you don't mind hacking the Tk, you can try like the following.(It may break in the future.)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values = ['red', 'green', 'blue'], state = 'readonly')
combo.pack()

def configure_items():
    lines = [f'set popdown [ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow {combo}]']
    for i, v in enumerate(combo['values']):
        lines.append(f'$popdown.f.l itemconfigure {i} -background {v}')
    root.tk.eval('\n'.join(lines))
combo.configure(postcommand=lambda: root.after_idle(configure_items))

root.mainloop()
```

To understand the above code, you need to see [the combobox.tcl](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/library/ttk/combobox.tcl) and [the listbox reference](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/listbox.html#M30).

Comment: I'll check what's better for my application, to hack or to use the custom widget. Thanks a lot!